# Is there a real location that resembles Moominvalley?

Tags: identify-this, finland

I do hope this question belongs here...
I want to know if there is a specific place that bears the most resemblance to Moominvalley, which is a fictional valley where Tove Jansson's books about the moomins take place. 
[image: Moomin books]

It is probably based on Finland's landscape, where the stories originated from, but I was wondering if there is any real valley that may be similar enough to moominvalley's depictions in pictures (see below) and [TV series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-VyXsPPq5w&t=1m35s)?

Some artist's representations of the valley:

[image]
[image]
[image]

By the way, I am aware of [Moomin World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moomin_World), although I haven't been there. Still, I'm looking for a natural place, not manmade.

Comment: +1 Absolutely a great question.  For me your descriptions and photographs evoked the Rhine scenery at the location of the Lorelei Monument. Google "lorelei monument" to see images.

Comment: The "small community nestled between the sea and the mountains" reminds me of Maunabo, Puerto Rico, but PR is tropical and the images above do not show a tropical climate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moominvalley):

> It was inspired by Ängsmarn, a family retreat in Sweden, which is also situated on a grassy field facing the sea and surrounded by rocky outcrops.

The [Finnish page](https://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muumilaakso) seems to indicate that the estate is on [Blidö](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blid%C3%B6).

Comment: Even though @phoog's answer is probably the most accurate one, I'd be happy if anyone coming across this question and recalling any other place similar to the pictures above will share it with us also.

Answer (score 5):

While @phoog has mentioned it was inspired by Angsmarn, there is also [Moomin World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moomin_World)!

> Moomin World (Muumimaailma in Finnish, Muminvärlden in Swedish) is the
>   Moomin Theme Park especially for children. Moomin World is located on
>   the island of Kailo beside the old town of Naantali, near the city of
>   Turku in Western Finland.

Answer (score 1):

Finland doesn't really have mountains like those in the Moomin valley, and is generally very flat. I believe Tone Jansson was inspired by the west coast of Norway. There are tons of valleys there that looks almost exactly like it, with the same  combination of ocean, mountains and forest.